# Why syntax error, code wont print in order

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I wrote two different sequences, how do I get them to print in order? Do I need to use a loop? If so how would i do that?

```
name = input("Who Goes There?")
print("Ah" , name , "-I'll Call You Ted Instead") 

water = input("Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?")
seagulls = input("What About The Seagulls?")
print(water, seagulls)
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you need to occur?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I just want the script to ask the questions in that order, but I get a syntax error for water, but if I do them separately they work.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to figure out what you're asking, particularly since there is no syntax error in that code. I'm *assuming* you're running it with the Python interpreter, yes<sup>(1)</sup>?

In any case, you only need a loop if you want to do things more than once. If all you want to do is execute some statements in sequence, you write them in the order desired, exactly as you have done, as the following transcript shows:

```
pax:~> python3 testprog.py
Who Goes There?pax
Ah pax -I'll Call You Ted Instead
Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?yes
What About The Seagulls?no
yes no
```

If the order of those actions is different to what you need, simply rearrange the statements into the order you *do* need.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The reason I ask is that you *do* get a syntax error if, for example, you try to run it with a shell:

```
pax:~> bash testprog.py
testprog.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
testprog.py: line 1: `name = input("Who Goes There?")'
```

But, if that's the case, you're just using the wrong tool to run it (possibly implicitly if it's executable and you just run it with `./testprog.py`. You may benefit from the use of a shebang line to specify a different interpreter in that case, something like (the actual line may be different on your system but the concept is the same):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = input("Who Goes There?")
print("Ah" , name , "-I'll Call You Ted Instead") 

water = input("Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?")
seagulls = input("What About The Seagulls?")
print(water, seagulls)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im using idle and Then running it in python. But I keep getting a syntax error and the “w” in water is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a script - then run the entire script - the order should execute top-down.

```py
name = input("Who Goes There?")
print("Ah" , name , "-I'll Call You Ted Instead") 
water = input("Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?")
seagulls = input("What About The Seagulls?")
print(water, seagulls)
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I put my script as you mentioned but still get a syntax error for water.

Comment: Check that your indentation is correct and you have not missed any brackets

Comment: Thank you!! It was the indentation. *face palm*

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
name = input("Who Goes There?") 
print(f"Ah {name} I'll call you Ted Instead")

water = input("Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?")
seagulls = input("What About The Seagulls?")
print(water, seagulls)
```

or if you want you can do this too

```
name = input("Who Goes There?") 
print("Ah {} I'll call you Ted Instead").format(name)

water = input("Ted, Dont You Miss The Water?")
seagulls = input("What About The Seagulls?")
print(water, seagulls)
```